# Get file information through api

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm not able to get information about a file.

Here it is my situation:

- I'm logged in google drive
- Through google picker I get the file ID
- Then I type the url `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v1/files/[file ID]`

But I get the following error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded. Please sign up",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded. Please sign up"
 }
}
```

How can I sort it out?

Comment: You have 7 open questions, 6 of which have answers, but have not accepted any answers. Please go back and accept answers where they've helped you. See the FAQ for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

You can't retrieve the file metadata by typing the url in your browser.

Instead you need to send an authorized request with a valid OAuth 2.0 token.
For more information:

https://developers.google.com/drive/about_auth

Comment: Ok. Thank you. About file information, is there a streaming url, like rtmp? Or you provide only the url to download the original file?

Comment: You only get the download link, no streaming url